# Efficient cache for results of comparisons

Tags: java, caching, data-structures

I am processing instance dumps from a heap dump. My goal is to find instances with duplicate data which means traversing the objects and their references. I need to speed it up, so I created a cache for comparisons I have already done, but the cache is very memory inefficient because it uses nested HashMaps. I would appreciate any advice on how to store the results of comparisons more efficiently. My main idea is storing ids of objects I have compared and storing the result of comparison, either they are duplicates, then I cache true, or they are not, then I cache false.

Here is the code for the current cache:

```
public class DefaultInstanceComparisonCache implements InstanceComparisonCache {

    private final Map<Long, Map<Long, Boolean>> cache = new HashMap<>();
    private long cacheHit = 0;
    private long cacheMiss = 0;

    @Override
    public Optional<Boolean> instancesEqual(InstanceDump a, InstanceDump b) {
        InstanceDump first = a.getInstanceId() < b.getInstanceId() ? a : b;
        InstanceDump second = first == a ? b : a;

        Optional<Boolean> result =  Optional.ofNullable(cache.get(first.getInstanceId()))
                .map(cachedComparison -> cachedComparison.get(second.getInstanceId()));
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            cacheHit++;
        } else {
            cacheMiss++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void cacheComparisonResult(InstanceDump a, InstanceDump b, boolean comparisonResult) {
        InstanceDump first = a.getInstanceId() < b.getInstanceId() ? a : b;
        InstanceDump second = first == a ? b : a;

        cacheResult(first.getInstanceId(), second.getInstanceId(), comparisonResult);
    }

    @Override
    public long getCacheHitCount() {
        return cacheHit;
    }

    @Override
    public long getCacheMissCount() {
        return cacheMiss;
    }

    private void cacheResult(long instanceKey, long comparedTo, boolean comparisonResult) {
        Map<Long, Boolean> cachedComparison = cache.computeIfAbsent(instanceKey, a -> new HashMap<>());
        cachedComparison.put(comparedTo, comparisonResult);
    }
}
```

What approach would be better in this case?

Comment: You probably want a single key and hash table. For example, a string of the form `first.getInstanceId() + ":" + second.getInstanceId()` would allow you to just have one `Map<String, Boolean>`, and will save a lookup at the cost of needing to build a String. Might be faster or slower, but will likely have less memory pressure as there will be less `HashMap` overhead.

Comment: I have thought of that and even implemented it, but sadly it's actually slower than current implementation on my machine.